# Errors LNK1120 and LNK 2019 in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++11

I have an fatal error in my program given like that:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall ApplicationManager::AddConnector(class Connector *)" (?AddConnector@ApplicationManager@@QAEXPAVConnector@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall AddConnectors::Execute(void)" (?Execute@AddConnectors@@UAEXXZ) C:\Users\akabbag\Desktop\Programming\CMP103 Project S2013 - ALL Docs - Students\Project Framework\AddConnectors.obj
```

And

```
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

............................

All what i've done that I have a Class called ApplicationManager.cpp with its .h file which call a new object from a class called (AddConnectors) inherted from an abstract class (Actions) which take a new pointer from the class Connectors (contains some functons i used) this is my sequence of work
I included in (AddConnectors.cpp) class both :

```
#include "AddConnectors.h"
#include "..\ApplicationManager.h"
```

And in (AddConnectors.h) both :

```
#include "Action.h"
#include "..\Statements\Connector.h"
```

I also defined :

```
#ifndef ADD_CONNECTORS_H
#define ADD_CONNECTORS_H
```

with its `#endif` in the end

....................
Seriously I have no idea why this error appear .. i read alot about these errors i found that one of the problems may be wrong defintion for the .h file of (AddConnectors) but there isn't
Also I found that maybe the Project is constructed from the begining wrongly So i made a new project Console Win 32!
So There any suggestions,please?

Comment: Have you added AddConnectors.cpp and ApplicationManager.cpp to your project? It's not that your project was constructed wrongly from the beginning, it might be that when you created these two new files you didn't also add them to your project.

Comment: Ensure that you not only see those *.cpp files in your Project/Solution, but also that they are **"included"** in your project. To be sure, rightclick on a file and check if in the context menu you see "Exclude" option. If you see it, that's OK. But if you see "Include" option, then press it. (SolutionExplorer presents also excluded files when you turn on the "ShowAllFiles" option)

Comment: The error is reporting linkage failure, not compilation failure. Thus the `#include` information is not particularly relevant. Were the include-files not locatable, your compile-step would have failed and you would have never reached link procurement. I see no evidence you're including the actual code behind the declarations we can only assume are in those headers in your compilation, much less in your linkage, in no small part because you've actually not shown any code *at all*

Comment: Captain obvlious .. Perfect! .. Thank you soo much it had worked now!

Comment: @AhmedHatem Actually `whozCraig` picked up on it first, I just didn't see his comment. He should make it an answer so you can accept it.